# Unable to display video in webpage using javaFx Webview (video is live on the given url)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

I am trying to display a live webpage in JavaFX Webview . Web page contains a video but that video not playing in javaFX webview .

Following is the comple code i am using it also contains the live url of my webpage. 
I want in my JavaFX web view video should be played through displayed live web page.

```
package webviewbrowser;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class WebViewBrowser extends Application {

 @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new WebViewPane();
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
   double width = screenSize.getWidth();
   double height = screenSize.getHeight();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, width, height));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public class WebViewPane extends Pane {

    public WebViewPane() {
        VBox.setVgrow(this, Priority.ALWAYS);
        setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        WebView view = new WebView();
        view.setMinSize(500, 400);
        view.setPrefSize(500, 400);
        final WebEngine eng = view.getEngine();
        try
        eng.load("http://techyadesh.com/video.php");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setVgap(5);
        grid.setHgap(5);
        GridPane.setConstraints(view, 0, 1, 2, 1, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER, Priority.ALWAYS, Priority.ALWAYS);
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(
                new ColumnConstraints(100, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true),
                new ColumnConstraints(40, 40, 40, Priority.NEVER, HPos.CENTER, true)
        );
       // grid.getChildren().addAll(locationField, goButton, view);
         grid.getChildren().addAll( view);
        getChildren().add(grid);
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        List<Node> managed = getManagedChildren();
        double width = getWidth();
        double height = getHeight();
        double top = getInsets().getTop();
        double right = getInsets().getRight();
        double left = getInsets().getLeft();
        double bottom = getInsets().getBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < managed.size(); i++) {
            Node child = managed.get(i);
            layoutInArea(child, left, top,
                           width - left - right, height - top - bottom,
                           0, Insets.EMPTY, true, true, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if the page opens in any javafx browser it will just open, if it doesn't it simply means javafx is not able to handle it. I will check and get back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine what you wrote. I tried it on javafx 13 and it just worked.
You missed brackets in a couple of places while pasting it in stackoverflow. Other than that I didn't see any mistake. Just upgrade your javafx and it should work.

Here is a working example with your exact code

https://github.com/shashaanktulsyan/java-javafx-maven-learning-tips/tree/master/nu-sharabheshwara-adesh_singh-webview

`mvn javafx:run`
should simply work.